# I am not able to sync my project with the gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I have tried importing my project and even updated the android studio and Gradle.
But I am not able to sync the Gradle with the project. Please help.

These are the error messages in the log-
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:23.3.0
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

And the error message in the event log-
NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN

Comment: post your gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add Google's Maven repository to your project's build.gradle file as described here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }
    }
```

For Android Studio 3.0.0 and above:

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
           google()
           jcenter()
           mavenCentral()
           maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

android forces you to use the latest versions, and one or more of your versions is not the latest, so what u can do:

go to https://mvnrepository.com/

there you can copy paste your com.android.support:appcompat-v7, or com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout or whatever, and you can see a list of versions. (do the copy paste without the version) so not com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3 but com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout.

Just an example, com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0, the latest version is 28.0.0 so you have to use that, not the 23.3.0.

After you have the latest version (if there is beta you can skip that and use the latest stable version), you will be able to sync.

Answer (score 0):

Is there this option in your gradle file?

```
repositories {
    google()
}
```

Comment: it's better to mention in which `build.gradle` file we should put these option. Whether it's app level or project level gradle file?. And also post some part of the `build.gradle` file as it's easy to understand where to put these option for the OP and future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

@Muskan Please observe errors which you are getting while syncing your gradle file,

```
These are the error messages in the log- ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3 Add Google Maven repository and sync project Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0 Add Google Maven repository and sync project Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0 Add Google Maven repository and sync project Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:23.3.0 Add Google Maven repository and sync project Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app

And the error message in the event log- NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN
```

> This clearly states that maven repo is missing at module level

You can google this error and you'll get a lot of useful answers which would clarify you why this is needed.

But answer to your question, you can do resolve this like this,

So Add Maven repository(Google) in module level gradle

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

Then if you want to use constrain layout then,

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:X.X.X'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:X.X.X'
```

If not you can uncheck the option from the Andorid Studio's Project settings!